# Use Memcache for php Classloader cache?

Tags: php, symfony, classloader

We are changing our hosting environment and they do not support apcu/xcache/wincache.
Currently we use apcu for Classloader cache in our Symfony PHP webapp as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/cache_class_loader.html).

Because that component does not come with a MemcachedClassloader, does it even make sense to implement the Classloader cache in Memcached (non-distributed setup)?

Comment: If you use composer optimize and opcode cache in your prod env you shouldn't loose to much in pure perf.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by COil and after reading the Symfony docs about [performance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html) I think we can just use the optimized flag for Composer autoload and tweak the settings for [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps).